# Removing space between marks in altair visualization

Tags: python, altair

I have a visualization where I am trying to increase mark size and also have them touching (decrease the space in-between the marks) using altair. Is there a way to do this without simply using 'size='? I would like to make this adaptable to a function and not hardcode the size, but have it dependable on the data given.

Here is my current code so far:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_square().encode(
x=alt.X('p1:N'),
y=alt.Y('p2:N'),
color=alt.Color('weight:O', legend=alt.Legend(type='symbol'), scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues'))
               
).properties(
    height=500,
    width=500
 )
```

My current output:

[image]

My intended output I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `mark_rect()` rather than `mark_square()` with a nominal or ordinal encoding, the size of each mark will automatically be adjusted to fill the space.

Answer (score 1):

`size` is propierty from `Altair` then is used to manipulate **Marks** size and so it is for `point/circle/square`, please check [altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks.html?highlight=mark_square](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks.html?highlight=mark_square). To show how it could be used through a function I did this:

```
def plot_mark_squares(df, bandsize=0, size=30, width=500, height=500):  
    alt.Chart(df).mark_square().encode(
    x=alt.X('p1:N'),
    y=alt.Y('p2:N'),
    color=alt.Color('weight:O', legend=alt.Legend(type='symbol'), scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues'))
    ).properties(
           height=500,
           width=500,
           bandsize=bandsize,
           size=size
    )

plot_mark_squares(df, 0.1, 50)
```